# Pandas `groupby` seems to only apply function to first group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with part-of-speech tags that I am trying to build a part-of-speech tagger with. It looks something like this.

```
silly_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"INDEX":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                        "LABEL": ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'Y']})
```

which looks like:

```
   INDEX LABEL
0      1     X
1      1     Y
2      1     Z
3      2     Z
4      2     Z
5      2     X
6      2     X
7      2     Y
```

The `INDEX` column groups tokens together, and each token has a label.

However, I would like to modify the labels to improve the performance of my model. I would like to convert each `"Z"` into either `"B-Z"` or `"I-Z"`, where `"B-Z"` indicates that we are at the **b**eginning of a (possibly length-1) string of `Z`'s, and "`I-Z`" indicates that we are on the **i**nside (or possibly the end) of a (length >1) string of `"Z"`'s. All of this transformation should take place *within* indices, so that the desired output is

```
   INDEX LABEL  NEW_LABEL
0      1     X          X
1      1     Y          Y
2      1     Z        B_Z
3      2     Z        B_Z
4      2     Z        I_Z
5      2     X          X
6      2     X          X
7      2     Y          Y
```

I have written some code which performs this relabeling on a single list of labels within one index level:

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def add_b_i(beg, inside, match, labels):
    for i, (s, t) in enumerate(pairwise(labels)):
        if t == match:
            if s != match:
                labels[i+1] = beg
            else:
                labels[i+1] = inside
    return labels
```

Now I would like this to apply this function groupwise, but when I try, I get:

```
silly_df.groupby('INDEX')['LABEL'].transform(lambda x: add_b_i('B-Z', 'I-Z', 'Z', x))
```

Output:

```
0      X
1      Y
2    B-Z
3      Z
4      Z
5      X
6      X
7      Y
```

It seems to only be applying the function to the first group. How come?

Comment: When you call transform, the group is passed as a dataframe. Iterating over the dataframe iterates over column names, so ``add_b_i`` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @jakevdp ah--so my mistake was writing add_b_i for a list and applying it on a Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this vectorized approach, (usually you don't need to *enumerate* on a Series object since it contains index already):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def add_b_i(beg, inside, match, labels):
    match_logic = labels == match
    match_count = match_logic.cumsum()
    return labels.where(~match_logic, 
                        np.where(match_logic & (match_count == 1), beg, inside))

silly_df.groupby('INDEX')['LABEL'].transform(lambda x: add_b_i('B-Z', 'I-Z', 'Z', x))

#0      X
#1      Y
#2    B-Z
#3    B-Z
#4    I-Z
#5      X
#6      X
#7      Y
#Name: LABEL, dtype: object
```